# PHP: Parsing XML

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have the following XML file:

```
<transcript_list docid="6678351850933011277">
<track id="1" name="" lang_code="en-GB" lang_original="English (United Kingdom)" lang_translated="English (United Kingdom)" lang_default="true"/>
<track id="2" name="" lang_code="fr" lang_original="Français" lang_translated="French"/>
<track id="3" name="" lang_code="de" lang_original="Deutsch" lang_translated="German"/>
</transcript_list>
```

As of now, this is the code I got so far:

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

if ($attrs = $sxml->track->attributes()) {

$attrs = $sxml->track->attributes();

//GET lang_code
$language = $attrs["lang_code"];

//GET name
$name = $attrs["name"];

//GET lang_original
$lang_original = $attrs["lang_original"];

//GET lang_translated
$lang_translated = $attrs["lang_translated"];

}

// ECHO values
echo "Language: ".$language." | Name: ".$name." | Language Original:".$lang_original." | Language Translated: ".$lang_translated;
```

Above PHP code works just fine for me, but it only prints the first line of the attributes.

How do I do the loop to echo all lines of the XML file?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look here [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I already know how to parse it, I just need to know how to loop through getting rest of the lines. Much appreciated.

Comment: you seams not to know... you speek about a loop but your code seams not to need a loop ... you need to parse the xml as an array then you can work with it as a single array ore multidimensional array in a loop

Comment: i get the point... working wih arrays will be ok also but you find the way for him ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the `track`s.

```
foreach($sxml->track as $track) {
    if ($attrs = $track->attributes()) {
        $language = $attrs["lang_code"];
        $name = $attrs["name"];
        $lang_original = $attrs["lang_original"];
        $lang_translated = $attrs["lang_translated"];
           echo "Language: ".$language." | Name: ".$name." | Language Original:".$lang_original." | Language Translated: ".$lang_translated . "\n";
    }
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/665762

Also note `if ($attrs = $sxml->track->attributes()) {` assigns `$sxml->track->attributes()` to `$attrs` so you don't need to do that a second time.

Comment: Wow, that was an amazing, concise and also a very quick answer. 
This is exactly what I needed, and now I also understand how it works... much appreciated...